# What does this logic mean in HAML/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this logic in my HAML layout, but I don't know what it means:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse{class: (params[:controller] == 'welcome' ? "navbar-fixed-top" : "navbar-static-top")}
```

Comment: See my answer. It may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a div with classes `navbar` and `navbar-inverse`.

Another class is there, which is conditional. if your controller is `welcome`, then the class will be `navbar-fixed-top` else `navbar-static-top`

The resulted HTML will be like this

```
In case params[:controller] is `welcome`
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"> </div>
```

For other values for params[:controller]

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @jyothu is saying, (I figured the SO needs more fundamental explanation)

**Its ternary if operator**

In Ruby,

```
1.9.3p385 :001 > a = 100

1.9.3p385 :002 > if a == 100
1.9.3p385 :003?>    b = 200
1.9.3p385 :004?>   else
1.9.3p385 :005 >     b = 300
1.9.3p385 :006?>   end

1.9.3p385 :007 > p b
200

1.9.3p385 :008 > b = (a == 100 ? 200 : 300) # one line if statement
1.9.3p385 :009 > p b
200
```

So this statement,

```
(params[:controller] == 'welcome' ? "navbar-fixed-top" : "navbar-static-top")
```

Would return "navbar-fixed-top" or "navbar-static-top" based on the value of the controller. '?' means, if and ':' means else.